# Sql Server is not combining the results , it is becoming mutually exclusive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a Table Variable and when attempting to filter down the data I have a condition that must be met.
User Story --  When HCPC_CODE Contains LCS AND the Allowed_AMT > 0  Then display these records

What I am seeing it that I try parenthesis around the data, but It treats the Allowed_AMT > 0 as if it is just another condition in the Where clause

Thus:

```
select * from @billingEdit where (HCPC_CODE NOT IN ('LCS%') AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0)
```

And

```
select * from @billingEdit where ALLOWED_AMT > 0
```

They Both return 1,056 records, but, I was changing to Omit the 'NOT' and even had a LIKE instead of the 'IN'

I must be super rusty with sql server as this should not be hard to do.....

**Would I want to do something like this instead?**

```
select * from @billingEdit where 
((HCPC_CODE LIKE('LCS%') AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0)
OR
(HCPC_CODE NOT LIKE('LCS%')
))
```

---

```
select * from @billingEdit   currently gives  1,069 records

select * from @billingEdit where (HCPC_CODE LIKE ('%LCS%') AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0)   gives zero records as in table variable there are NO LCS (changes every hour) 


select * from @billingEdit where ALLOWED_AMT > 0   -- gives  1,056 records

select * from @billingEdit where HCPC_CODE like 'LCS%'   -- gives 0 records as expected for right now
```

Comment: `NOT IN ('LCS%')` will likely match everything - it does't handle LIKE wildcards. Please post the *actual* query that "fails".

Comment: What exactly is the question? There's nothing unreasonable about `SELECT * FROM @billingEdit WHERE HCPC_CODE LIKE '%LCS%' AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0;`.

Comment: LIKE LCS AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0   .... what is wrong and that if there are zero LCS records that i get zero results

Comment: ONLY pull records Like LCS WHEN tied to record containing LCS in the row.... when allowed_amt > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third query should work. Just change `LCS%` to `%LCS%`. This would handle `HCPC_CODE` that begins with `LCS`, ends with `LCS` or has `LCS` in the middle. Considering your `HCPC_CODE` could also be null, your query should look something like this -

```
select * from @billingEdit
where (HCPC_CODE like '%LCS%' and ALLOWED_AMT > 0)
or (isnull(HCPC_CODE,'') not like '%LCS%');
```

Here's the sqlfiddle that I have tried -> <kbd>**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec545/7)**</kbd>

Comment: SQL Fiddle I forgot about that.  NICE!!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, it looks like just need to change the "NOT IN" to "LIKE" and add your wildcard to the beginning of LCS.

Also, you don't need the parenthesis around the LSC.

```
select * from @billingEdit where (HCPC_CODE LIKE '%LCS%' AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0) OR HCPC_CODE NOT LIKE '%LCS%'
```

Comment: I get all the records with this   select * from @billingEdit  but when I run your statement I get zero records.   So no.... I want the where clause condition to ONLY show LCS records when the allowed_amt > 0  ,   currently there are zero records with HCPC_CODE Like the LCS  ( changes on a sql job per hour )

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your second condition. It seems like your third query should have worked.

Comment: This one?    select * from @billingEdit where 
((HCPC_CODE LIKE('LCS%') AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0)
OR
(HCPC_CODE NOT LIKE('LCS%')
))

Comment: That should work, as long as 'LCS' is the first characters of your field. Otherwise you will need the wildcard at the beginning too (LIKE '%LCS%').

Comment: No, the whole point is that if even part of word is 'LCS', only show those LCS records that have Allowed_Amt > 0   , BUT ALSO STILL DISPLAY ALL THE REST OF THE RECORDS....

Comment: It sounds to me like you have no records in your db that have an hcpc_code of LCS and an allowed_amt greater than zero.

Comment: Correct, there is a Job that runs every hour and so sometimes there are records that do have LCS in the column name.  I am just trying to make sure the logic is correct to display everything, but when LCS is encountered say 10 records, not to display say ..the ones that have an allowed_amt = 0  , but must be an LCS record with allowed_amt > 0 ,  but still return ALL the other non-LCS records too regardless of the allowed_amt !   thx

Answer (score 0):

I say do this that you provided...

```
select * from @billingEdit where 
((HCPC_CODE LIKE('LCS%') AND ALLOWED_AMT > 0)
OR
(HCPC_CODE NOT LIKE('LCS%')
))
```